# Batman/Clayface story about a death cult made of teenage horror fans

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, batman

I'm trying to find the Batman comic that centered around Clayface and a death cult made up of teenage horror fans.

Anyone know the story, and/or what the comic was, or the number of the comic, if it was a Batman story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question is a bit thin on details; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if you can remember any more details to [edit] into your question.  For example, how long ago was this?

Comment: @DavidW - It's not wonderfully detailed, but it's more than sufficient to make a positive ID

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough; I've been on your side of this conversation too. :)  But without knowing, it's hard to know, and it doesn't hurt to ask for more info just in case...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Joker's Ayslum II - Clayface](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Joker%27s_Asylum:_Clayface_Vol_1_1). And yes, Batman features prominently.

> The Joker tells a story about Clayface, involving an old film that he starred in called "The Terror", and a group of teens, the "Children of the Clay" that idolize him.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Valorum. That's the one!